# How to detect position of dragable object [android]

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I do drag object through **View.DragShadowBuilder** and **startDrag**.
How i can find position in onMove action of draggable object (bitmap drawed on canvas) ?
I set **setOnDragListener** but it only catch **start**, **end** but not **onMove** event.

**onTouch** event stop dispatching after i set **setOnDragListener** too.

Answer (score 0):

you can get ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION event from DragListener, where you can get position.

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't dispatched for some reason. but i received DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED and DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED and that strange.

Comment: the parent view's `onTouch()` should be dispatched, you can get position there.